# Automating Color picker using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium java.

I have a color picker in a dialog which I am testing. The goal is to choose a color for a text:

```
<input id="EditorColorPicker1" type="color" style="width: 100%;">
```

I need to click on a color on this dialog and then close it:

[image]

Thanks in advance.
Roshni

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is a windows color picker dialog, You can use the javascript to change the color as given below. Here no need to click on color picker input box.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementByid('EditorColorPicker1').value='#FFEEXX'");
```

Comment: This worked . i was trying to figure out how i will click on a color and then how will i close the dialog after that. Thank you for the solution. i could avoid those steps.

Answer (score 0):

For web page color picker you can try below code:

```
WebElement img = dr.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='img_colormap.gif']"));
WebElement banner = img.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"colormap\"]"));
WebElement area = banner.findElement(By.xpath("//area[@alt='#003366']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)dr;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", area);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not click directly in any color as this is a window based popup, for this, I recommend to use any window automation tool like AutoIT. I will recommend using Sikuli, coz it will make your task much easier if you get further scenario similar to this.
Meanwhile, I agree with @Murthi, this is the perfect way to complete your task.